# Regex to set input value between 1 to 10 using bootstrap-validate.js

Tags: javascript, bootstrapvalidator

i want to validate input by regex i am using bootstrap-validate.js
https://bootstrap-validate.js.org/
here is my code

it is accepting 0 to 11 i want it to be 0 to 10 it is not accepting 12, 13 and so on

```
<html>
<form id="rqStudent" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="b_marks" class="form-control" id="b_m" maxlength="2" required/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-12">Request</button>
</form>

<script src="js/bootstrap-validate.js"></script>
<script>
bootstrapValidate('#b_m', 'required|numeric:Please only enter numeric characters!|regex:^[0-10]+$:only 0-10 value acceptable');
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your title and body have contradictory min values. Is it 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```
/^(?:10|[1-9])$/
```

```js
for (let i=0; i<15; i++)
    console.log(i, /^(?:10|[1-9])$/.test(i) );
```

Comment: Geeting this error : SyntaxError: invalid regexp group

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can match a single digit or 10

```
/^(?:\d|10)$/
```

```js
const result = ['0', '1', '5', '8', '10', '11', '15'].map(
    str => `${str} is ${str.match(/^(?:\d|10)$/) ? 'valid' : 'invalid'}`
)

document.write(result.join('<br />'))
```

Comment: Geeting this error : SyntaxError: invalid regexp group